# How to customize json response?

Tags: php, json

I request a JSON query and get the output, I want to parse that output and show it in tabular form also want to insert it into database.

I performed following php code to get array representation of JSON data.

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r( json_decode( $result ) );
echo '</pre>';
```

and I get following output:

```
stdClass Object
(
[request] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Target] => Affiliate_Report
        [Format] => json
        [Service] => HasOffers
        [Version] => 3
        [Method] => getConversions
        [api_key] => 
        [NetworkId] => 
        [limit] => 2
        [fields] => Array
            (
                [0] => Offer.name
                [1] => Browser.display_name
                [2] => Stat.payout
                [3] => Stat.sale_amount
                [4] => Stat.status
                [5] => Stat.datetime
                [6] => Stat.ip
                [7] => Stat.ad_id
                [8] => Stat.affiliate_info1
            )

    )

[response] => stdClass Object
    (
        [status] => 1
        [httpStatus] => 200
        [data] => stdClass Object
            (
                [page] => 1
                [current] => 2
                [count] => 81
                [pageCount] => 41
                [data] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [Offer] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [name] => Myntra (CPS)
                                    )

                                [Browser] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [display_name] => Firefox
                                    )

                                [Stat] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [payout] => 150.00000
                                        [sale_amount] => 0.00000
                                        [status] => approved
                                        [datetime] => 2014-05-20 22:20:05
                                        [ip] => 27.0.50.82
                                        [ad_id] => 102fa12e74df6018e502d8e152adb2
                                        [affiliate_info1] => 
                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [Offer] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [name] => Myntra (CPS)
                                    )

                                [Browser] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [display_name] => Firefox
                                    )

                                [Stat] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [payout] => 150.00000
                                        [sale_amount] => 53.00000
                                        [status] => rejected
                                        [datetime] => 2014-03-30 13:14:50
                                        [ip] => 27.0.51.145
                                        [ad_id] => 102be1d682ac9b2e9ee8e14dd1aeca
                                        [affiliate_info1] => 
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [dbSource] => branddb
            )

        [errors] => Array
            (
            )

        [errorMessage] => 
    )

)
```

I want to display above data into tabular form.

Code used by me:

```
$result = file_get_contents($base);

$obj = json_decode($result, true);

<?php foreach ($obj['response'] as $licenseElement) :?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $licenseElement->data->Offer->name; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $licenseElement->Stat->payout; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $licenseElement->Stat->sale_amount; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $licenseElement->Stat->datetime; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This code returns me an error **Trying to get property of non-object** everywhere at echo syntax.

Please help me to parse the above json output and display it in proper tabular format.

Comment: Try `foreach ($obj->response->data->data as $licenseElement)` and in loop use without `data` index like `$licenseElement->Offer->name;`

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301852/how-to-parse-json-data-into-tabular-form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are iterating over wrong object, you need to loop over `$obj->response->data->data` object to get what you are seeking

```
<?php foreach ($obj->response->data->data as $licenseElement) :?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $licenseElement->Offer->name; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $licenseElement->Stat->payout; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $licenseElement->Stat->sale_amount; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $licenseElement->Stat->datetime; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting to the right level in the object hierarchy.  Try with

```
foreach($obj->response->data->data as $licenseElement) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = file_get_contents($base);

$obj = json_decode($result, true);

<?php foreach ($obj['response']->data->data as $licenseElement) :?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $licenseElement->data->Offer->name; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $licenseElement->Stat->payout; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $licenseElement->Stat->sale_amount; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $licenseElement->Stat->datetime; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This code should work.
What you are trying to do is that you have considered the response as an array but the print_r functions lets us know wether your data is an array or an object.

It says StdClass Object  thats why we need the "->" sign to refer to it.

All i have changed is the foreach($obj['response']->data->data as $licenseElement)

We also need to check the levels , here we are 3 levels in. :)

Hope this helps.